# Angular Controllers and Services

Tags: node.js, angularjs, web, mean-stack

I'm pretty new to web dev and AngularJS. I'm trying to figure out how to use services and I'm following this tutorial: http://scotch.io/bar-talk/setting-up-a-mean-stack-single-page-application

How does the service connect with the controller? Is this done implicitly? I understand that you can inject the service into the controller, but how is it being done in the tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You inject your service into your controller. Like this. The reason behind services are that you want to keep your controller as 'skinny' as possible. All heavy logic/requests should be outsourced to the service.

```
app.service('myService', function(){
  this.name = 'Tyler';
}

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, myService){
  $scope.name = myService.name;
}
```

Another benefit of using a service is that you could inject that service into more than one controller. A good example is if you had a service that made a HTTP request. Instead of recreating the same code in every controller to make the request, you could simply create a service that did the request and inject that service into every controller you needed that functionality.

edit: To answer your question. You need to be sure to place the service in the controller on the same 'module'. Meaning. In your HTML you have something like this.

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
```

That's telling the whole BODY that whatever is nested inside it belongs to the 'myAPP' app. Then you usually have an app.js file that has something like this.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

Notice that the angular.module takes two parameters. You're telling angular to create a new app called 'myApp' (which coincides with your HTML).

Then in your controller, service, directive files you'll have something like this at the top.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');
```

Notice this one is only taking one parameter, the name of the app. You're telling angular that instead of creating a new app, you're going and 'getting' the one you already build. You'll then stick your controllers, directives, services on this app and as long as things are on the same app, you'll be able to inject them.

Another EDIT to your comment.

In the tutorial they're doing it a little weird. They're creating new modules for every controller, service, etc. It's not bad, just different. Doing it this way confuses me so I just prefer to stick everything under one module. In the tutorial this is the line that's gluing it all together.

```
// public/js/app.js
angular.module('sampleApp', ['ngRoute', 'appRoutes', 'MainCtrl', 'NerdCtrl', 'NerdService', 'GeekCtrl', 'GeekService']);
```

They have a sampleApp then all there other modules they build are being injected into the main sample app.

Comment: So in the tutorial, he places the service and controller in different folders. To inject the service into the controller, do the service and controller need to be in the same file? Also where in the, for example, GeekCtrl.js is the injection happening? I don't see the GeekService being used in it.

Comment: Edited my answer to answer your question. @Soubriquet

Comment: Ok. So then in the tutorial the service is being implicitly injected into the controller in the app.js file?

Comment: Edited again. @Soubriquet

Comment: Ok. How does the program know that the GeekCtrl.js corresponds to the GeekService.js?

Answer (score 0):

a service means to be accesible from all controllers, a service is a constructor, every controller can read or write in a service,  in order to use a service you must call a service in this way:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.service('sharedProperties', function() {
    var stringValue = 'test string value';
    var objectValue = {
        data: 'test object value'
    };

    return {
        getString: function() {
            return stringValue;
        },
        setString: function(value) {
            stringValue = value;
        },
        getObject: function() {
            return objectValue;
        }
    }
});

app.controller('myController1', function($scope, sharedProperties) {
    $scope.setOnController1 = function(sharedPoperties){
    $scope.stringValue = sharedProperties.getString();
    $scope.objectValue = sharedProperties.getObject().data;
    }
});

app.controller('myController2', function($scope, sharedProperties) {
    $scope.stringValue = sharedProperties.getString;
    $scope.objectValue = sharedProperties.getObject();
    $scope.setString = function(newValue) {
        $scope.objectValue.data = newValue;
        sharedProperties.setString(newValue);
    //some code to set values on screen at controller1
    };

});
```

Here is the JS FIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/b2fCE/228/

Comment: I'm pretty sure since you're using a service and not a factory you need to stick your methods on 'this' rather than returning an object.